# MKCOL 405 and LOCK 500 on git push (error: cannot lock existing info/refs)

Tags: apache-2.2, git, webdav

I'm having some troubles setting up a Git server with apache.

Here is my gitrepo.conf:

```
DavLockDB "opt/local/apache2/var/DavLock"

<Directory /opt/local/apache2/htdocs/repo>
  DAV On
  Deny from all
  AuthType Basic
  AuthName "Git repositories"
  AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/other/htpasswd
  AuthGroupFile /etc/apache2/other/htgroup-git
</Directory>

<Directory /opt/local/apache2/htdocs/repo/myproject.git>
  Allow from all
  Order allow,deny
  <Limit GET>
    Require group myproject-reader
  </Limit>
  <Limit GET PUT POST DELETE PROPFIND PROPPATCH MKCOL COPY MOVE LOCK UNLOCK>
    Require group myproject-writer
  </Limit>
</Directory>
```

When I `git push` to `http://admin@localhost/repo/myproject.git`, I get this:

```
error: cannot lock existing info/refs
fatal: git-http-push failed
```

Here is a snip from my access_log:

```
::1 - - [28/Jul/2012:19:05:52 +0100] "GET /repo/myproject.git/info/refs?service=git-receive-pack HTTP/1.1" 401 401
::1 - admin [28/Jul/2012:19:05:52 +0100] "GET /repo/myproject.git/info/refs?service=git-receive-pack HTTP/1.1" 401 401
::1 - admin [28/Jul/2012:19:05:55 +0100] "GET /repo/myproject.git/info/refs?service=git-receive-pack HTTP/1.1" 200 -
::1 - admin [28/Jul/2012:19:05:55 +0100] "GET /repo/myproject.git/HEAD HTTP/1.1" 200 23
::1 - - [28/Jul/2012:19:05:57 +0100] "PROPFIND /repo/myproject.git/ HTTP/1.1" 401 401
::1 - admin [28/Jul/2012:19:05:57 +0100] "PROPFIND /repo/myproject.git/ HTTP/1.1" 207 558
::1 - admin [28/Jul/2012:19:05:57 +0100] "HEAD /repo/myproject.git/info/refs HTTP/1.1" 200 -
::1 - admin [28/Jul/2012:19:05:57 +0100] "HEAD /repo/myproject.git/objects/info/packs HTTP/1.1" 200 -
::1 - admin [28/Jul/2012:19:05:57 +0100] "MKCOL /repo/myproject.git/info/ HTTP/1.1" 405 249
::1 - admin [28/Jul/2012:19:05:57 +0100] "LOCK /repo/myproject.git/info/refs HTTP/1.1" 500 535
```

I seem to be getting error 405 with MKCOL and error 500 with LOCK.

And here's my error_log:

```
[Sat Jul 28 19:05:52 2012] [error] [client ::1] user admin: authentication failure for "/repo/myproject.git/info/refs": Password Mismatch
[Sat Jul 28 19:05:57 2012] [error] [client ::1] Could not LOCK /repo/myproject.git/info/refs due to a failed precondition (e.g. other locks).  [500, #0]
[Sat Jul 28 19:05:57 2012] [error] [client ::1] The locks could not be queried for verification against a possible "If:" header.  [500, #0]
[Sat Jul 28 19:05:57 2012] [error] [client ::1] Could not open the lock database.  [500, #400]
[Sat Jul 28 19:05:57 2012] [error] [client ::1] (2)No such file or directory: Could not open property database.  [500, #1]
```

And I **am** entering the correct password as commands like `git remote show origin` which asks for the password accepts it fine.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the fix, and it was such a simple one too.

This:

`DavLockDB "opt/local/apache2/var/DavLock"`

should've been this:

`DavLockDB "/opt/local/apache2/var/DavLock"`

notice the `/` at the beginning of the filename.